# How to keep two different objects in List in java?

Tags: java

I want to create list and I have two different objects like employee and user .If I need employee and user object both into the list. Where will write the employee object and where will write user object . How to make different objects list view.

Comment: Looks like a design smell. Why not wrap 2 separate lists into a common java class and provide right accessors.

Comment: You either have a List of Objects, or if User and Employee classes are related, you have a List of the super class or interface. Please show us what you have coded so far.

Comment: This can be done easily by making the `List` as holding any `Object` type: `List<Object> list = new List<Object>`. But keep in mind, this is an **extremely** bad idea and very poor design. That being said, we have no idea what you are trying to accomplish...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am certain that there is a better way to achieve what you want. Try writing down what you need to do, and think of ways to store the different objects.

However, to directly answer your question you can make a generic list of `Object` like so:

```
List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<Object>();
myList.add(employee);
myList.add(user);
```

Beware that this will store any type of object, so whenever you take things back out of the list you will need to check what sort of object it is and then cast it like so:

```
if (myList.get(x) instanceof Employee)
{
    //Cast to an Employee and then do whatever you want
    Employee fromList = (Employee)myList.get(x);
}
else if (myList.get(x) instanceof User)
{
    //Cast to an User and then do whatever you want
    User fromList = (User)myList.get(x);
}
```